# Bash: Split two strings directly into associative array

Tags: bash, split, associative-array

I have two strings of same number of substrings divided by a delimiter.

I need to create key-value pairs from substrings.

Short example:
Input:

```sh
firstString='00011010:00011101:00100001'
secondString='H:K:O'
delimiter=':'
```

Desired result:

```sh
${translateMap['00011010']} -> 'H'
${translateMap['00011101']} -> 'K'
${translateMap['00100001']} -> 'O'
```

So, I wrote:

```sh
IFS="$delimiter" read -ra fromArray <<< "$firstString"
IFS="$delimiter" read -ra toArray <<< "$secondString"
declare -A translateMap

curIndex=0
for from in "${fromArray[@]}"; do
    translateMap["$from"]="${toArray[curIndex]}"
    ((curIndex++))
done
```

Is there any way to create the associative array directly from 2 strings without the unneeded arrays and loop? Something like:

```sh
IFS="$delimiter" read -rA translateMap["$(read -ra <<< "$firstString")"] <<< "$secondString"
```

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm afraid it isn't possible to assign everything without a loop (apart from creating a bash command using other tools and then using `eval`/`declare` on that). I checked all hits for the keyword `associative` in the [bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html) and couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A (somewhat convoluted) variation on @accdias's answer of assigning the values via the `declare -A` command, but will need a bit of explanation for each step ...

First we need to break the 2 variables into separate lines for each item:

```
$ echo "${firstString}" | tr "${delimiter}" '\n'
00011010
00011101
00100001

$ echo "${secondString}" | tr "${delimiter}" '\n'
H
K
O
```

What's nice about this is that we can now process these 2 sets of key/value pairs as separate files.

NOTE: For the rest off this discussion I'm going to replace `"${delimiter}"` with `':'` to make this a tad bit (but not much) less convoluted.

Next we make use of the `paste` command to merge our 2 'files' into a single file; we'll also designate ']' as the delimiter between key/value mappings:

```
$ paste -d ']' <(echo "${firstString}" | tr ':' '\n') <(echo "${secondString}" | tr ':' '\n')
00011010]H
00011101]K
00100001]O
```

We'll now run these results through a couple `sed` patterns to build our array assignments:

```
$ paste -d ']' <(echo "${firstString}" | tr ':' '\n') <(echo "${secondString}" | tr ':' '\n') | sed 's/^/[/g;s/]/]=/g'
[00011010]=H
[00011101]=K
[00100001]=O
```

What we'd like to do now is use this output in the `typeset -A` command but unfortunately we need to build the entire command and then `eval` it:

```
$ evalstring="typeset -A kv=( "$(paste -d ']' <(echo "${firstString}" | tr ':' '\n') <(echo "${secondString}" | tr ':' '\n') | sed 's/^/[/g;s/]/]=/g')" )"

$ echo "$evalstring"
typeset -A kv=( [00011010]=H
[00011101]=K
[00100001]=O )
```

If we want to remove the carriage returns and put on a single line we append another `tr` at the output from the `sed` command:

```
$ evalstring="typeset -A kv=( "$(paste -d ']' <(echo "${firstString}" | tr ':' '\n') <(echo "${secondString}" | tr ':' '\n') | sed 's/^/[/g;s/]/]=/g' | tr '\n' ' ')" )"

$ cat "${evalstring}"
typeset -A kv=( [00011010]=H [00011101]=K [00100001]=O )
```

At this point we can `eval` our auto-generated `typeset -A` command:

```
$ eval "${evalstring}"
```

And now loop through our array displaying the key/value pairs:

```
$ for i in ${!kv[@]}; do echo "kv[${i}] = ${kv[${i}]}"; done
kv[00011010] = H
kv[00100001] = O
kv[00011101] = K
```

Hey, I did say this would be a bit convoluted! :-)

Comment: It eval works perfectly! 
Can we do that it was not `( [00011010]=H, [00100001]=O, [00011101]=K ) `
But `( [00011010]="H", [00100001]="O", [00011101]="K" ) `
Even better is `( ["00011010"]="H", ["00100001"]="O", ["00011101"]="K" ) `

Comment: `sed "s/^/[\"/g; s/]/\"]/g; s/]/]=\"/g;"`
Mostly completed it. But don't know how to paste last \" properly

Comment: @kvantour sorry, wasn't copying your answer; you've edited your answer a few times until you came up with the answer that's similar to mine; it took me awhile to compose/post my message ... which appears to have occurred right about the time you (re)(re)edited your answer

Comment: Be advised that [`eval` is evil](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and could lead to unexpected results.

Comment: and `echo -e` has some issues, too

Comment: @anotherCryptoFun for the last `\"` you could try `s/$/\"/g`

Comment: I tried it already and it's matched the whole string, not parts. xD

Comment: Guys markp, @kvantour, thank you sooo much. It finally works, has less code and actually works faster than loop and two arrays. (don't know how).

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1):

It is probably not what you expect, but this works:

```
key_string="A:B:C:D"
val_string="1:2:3:4"
declare -A map
while [ -n "$key_string" ] && [ -n "$val_string" ]; do
    IFS=: read -r key key_string <<<"$key_string"
    IFS=: read -r val val_string <<<"$val_string"
    map[$key]="$val"
done

for key in "${!map[@]}"; do echo "$key => ${map[$key]}"; done
```

It uses recursion in the `read` function to reassign the string value. 
The downside of this method is that it destroys the original strings. The while-loop checks constantly if both strings have a non-zero length.

Next to the above in pure bash, you could any command to generate the associative array. See [How do I populate a bash associative array with command output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417793/how-do-i-populate-a-bash-associative-array-with-command-output/39418782#39418782)

This generally looks like:

```
declare -A map="( $( magic_command ) )"
```

where the `magic_command` generates an output like

```
[key1]=val1
[key2]=val2
[key3]=val3
```

In this case we use the command:

```
paste -d "" <(echo "[${key_string//:/]=$'\n'[}]=") \
            <(echo "${val_string//:/$'\n'}")
```

where we use [bash substitution to replace the delimiter with a newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7129047/new-line-in-bash-parameter-substitution-rev-n). However, any other `magic_command` might do. For completion:

```
key_string="A:B:C:D"
val_string="1:2:3:4"
declare -A map="( $(paste -d "" <(echo "[${key_string//:/]=$'\n'[}]=") \
                                <(echo "${val_string//:/$'\n'}"))      )"
for key in "${!map[@]}"; do echo "$key => ${map[$key]}"; done
```

Both examples generate the following output

```
D => 4
C => 3
B => 2
A => 1
```

Comment: It is a nice idea. But it doesn't work or I'm doing something wrong.
Can you explain how it works?

How "hash" was declared? Can it be used like this `${hash[$currentKey]}` ?

Comment: I renamed the variable `hash` into `map`. It is just the name of your associative array. So you declare it with `declare -A map`

Comment: Command version works, but I got error of array assign.
At least, you done the most closer thing to what I'm asked.
I'll be playing around with
`declare -A map="( $(paste -d "" <(echo -e "[${string1//:/]=\\n[}]=") \
                                <(echo -e "${string2//:/\\n}")) )"`
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly the answer for what you asked but at least it is shorter:

```sh
key='00011010:00011101:00100001'
value='H:K:O'
ifs=':'

IFS="$ifs" read -ra keys <<< "$key"
IFS="$ifs" read -ra values <<< "$value"
declare -A kv

for ((i=0; i<${#keys[*]}; i++)); do
    kv[${keys[i]}]=${values[i]}
done
```

As a side note, you can initialize an associative array in one step with:

```sh
declare -A kv=([key1]=value1 [key2]=value2 [keyn]=valuen)
```

But I don't know how to use that in your case.

Answer (score 0):

If values in your strings won't use spaces i would suggest this approach

```
firstString='00011010:00011101:00100001'
secondString='H:K:O'
delimiter=':'

declare -A translateMap

firstArray=( ${firstString//$delimiter/' '} )
secondArray=( ${secondString//$delimiter/' '} )

for i in ${!firstArray[@]}; {
    translateMap[firstArray[$i]}]=${secondArray[$i]}
}
```